# python regex get text among two tag with new line

Tags: python, regex

I'm new in regex.Here is my data.

```
<p>[tag]y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38[/tag]</p>
```

I want to get this.

```
y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38
```

Here is my regex.

```
(<p>\[tag(.*)\])(.+)(\[\/tag\]<\/p>)
```

But it doesn't work because of new line(\n).If I use re.DOTALL , It works ,but if my data has multi records like

```
<p>[tag]y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38[/tag]</p>

<p>[tag]y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38[/tag]</p>
```

re.findall() returns only one match.I briefly want this.
[data1,data2,data3...].What can i do ?

Comment: where is he data coming from?

Comment: You can use the dotall modifier along with a non-greedy match ... `re.findall(r'(?s)<p>\[tag](.*?)\[/tag]</p>', text)`

Comment: But I would probably use Beatuiful Soup to extract the text from the paragraph tags then grab the content between those tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a this regex:

```
\[tag\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/tag\]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pC4iY4/1)**

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [8-44]  `y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38`
```

Update: what

```
\[tag\]
([\s\S]*?) --> the [\s\S]*? is used to match everything, since \S will capture
               all non blanks and \s will capture blanks. This is just a trick, you can
               also use [\D\d] or [\W\w]. Btw, the *? is just a ungreedy quantifier
\[\/tag\]
```

On the other hand, if you want to allow attributes in the tag you can use:

```
\[tag.*?\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/tag\]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you explain "\s\S" and additionally what if I want to get parameters of tag like [tag id="5" a="3"].For example

<p>[tag id="5" a="5"]y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38[/tag]</p>

get 
`y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38`
and id=5 and a=5

Comment: I asked many question ,but '[tag(.*?)]([\s\S]*?)[\/tag]' and I can get parameters such as id and name.
For example [tag id="5" name="name"] and I have "id=5 and name=name" string , What is the best way to seperate this parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
\](.*?)\[

reobj = re.compile(r"\](.*?)\[", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
result = reobj.findall(YOURSTRING)
```

---

**Output:**

```
y,m,m,l
1997,f,e,2.34g
2000,m,c,2.38
```

---

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rS6pA7/1)

---

Regex Explanation:

```
\] matches the character ] literally
1st Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
\[ matches the character [ literally
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters
```